# Why did Constantinople get the works? -- what exactly does that mean?

Tags: comprehension

From the song *Istanbul (Not Constantinople)*:

> So take me back to Constantinople
>   No, you can't go back to Constantinople
>   Been a long time gone, Constantinople
>   **Why did Constantinople get the works?**
>   That's nobody's business but the Turks

What do they mean by *get the works*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The works* is a colloquial expression meaning the entirety of something: a hamburger with the works, for instance, is a hamburger with all available condiments and relishes.

To "get the works" is typically employed with legal sentences: to be sentenced to the most severe punishment permitted. This expression corresponds to "give [someone] the works", to deal out the most severe punishment permitted.

The name "Constantinople" got the works: it received an onomastic death penalty, being completely replaced by the Turkish derivative, "Istanbul".

Comment: There is an apocryphal story that the **turkish derivative** is of Greek origin. The aproaching Turks asked a Greek peasant where the road led, and he said  "εἰς τὴν Πόλιν" (eis tin bolin), which means "into the city".

Comment: Heh! It's only _apocryphal_ if you ask the Turks!